# I want to send a string to mysql with special chars using java

Tags: java, mysql, query-string

I'm using Java 1.7 to make an aplication how conects to a MySQL DB.But I Have many problems into que insertion of values with the special characters like ",\,\n.
I'm Trying to change manually this values.
Im using this method to make the change.

```
public static String StringToSQL(String chain) {
    chain.replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\"),
            Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\\\"));
    chain.replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement("\""),
            Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\\""));
    chain.replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement("\n"),
            Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\n"));
    chain.replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement("'"),
            Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\'"));
    return chain;
}
```

I wanna try to transform a chain like

```
The cat says "meaw meaw"
```

into

```
the cat says \"meaw meaw\"
```

to haven't problems with the MySql Syntax

for example the sql must be

```
INSERT INTO AnimalSays (Phrase) VALUES ("\"Meaw Meaw\"");
```

but I send

```
INSERT INTO AnimalSays (Phrase) VALUES (""Meaw Meaw"");
```

Having a syntax error how breaks the application

Comment: The problem is not using placeholders (aka prepared statements). Please follow through an applicable database tutorial and see http://bobby-tables.com/ which includes some assorted Java examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a prepared statement will solve your problem. It will escape all special characters if you set the string parameter.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Comment: thanks. I forget that It's mysql Inyection that I want prevent